# Recursively adding data from scratch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Suppose I have a table that looks like this (using C# for example):

```
public class Table {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Guid ParentId {get; set;}
}
```

This is a recursive table where a row can have a linked parent in the same table.

Assuming I am starting from scratch (i.e. there is no data to select from originally from other tables), what is the best way to insert new rows of up to depth X via TSQL?

Suppose I want the data to look something like this:

[image: Intended data model]

The purpose of this script is for load testing - thus I don't have any data I can select from. Data is continually going to be added, deleted, and added again. Most of what I've found are either SELECT CTE's or INSERT after SELECT.

I'm sure an alternative is to write a console app to do this for me (admittedly my SQL game is not that great), but I'd like to see if there's a way to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special (necessarily) about this data. You can script inserts as a sql insert statement. For example, using `int` instead of `guid` ID values for simplicity here:

```
create table Scratch (
    id int,
    [name] nvarchar(100),
    parentId int, 
    primary key (id))

alter table Scratch add constraint fk_temp_id 
    foreign key (parentId) references Scratch(id)

insert into Scratch (id, [Name], ParentId)
values 
    (1, 'a', null),
    (2, 'b', 1),
    (3, 'c', 1),
    (4, 'd', 2),
    (5, 'e', 2),
    (6, 'f', 3),
    (7, 'g', 3)
```

That being said, here is how you could create the data with a loop up to `N` levels deep - but more than 63 levels will overflow the `bigint` sequence values (and this could start to take a bit of time as number of levels increases - just 20 levels will be a million rows).

```
create table dbo.Scratch (
    id uniqueidentifier,
    [name] nvarchar(100),
    parentId uniqueidentifier, 
    seq int,
    parentSeq int,
    primary key (id));

alter table dbo.Scratch add constraint fk_temp_id 
    foreign key (parentId) references Scratch(id);

-- seed first row
insert into dbo.Scratch (id, [name], parentId, seq, parentSeq) values (newid(), '1', null, 1, null);

-- build binary tree with int ids
declare @I int = 0;
declare @J int = 0;
declare @K int;
declare @LEVELS int = 3; --> To be set as needed, using zero-based counting
declare @next_node bigint = 2;
while @I < @LEVELS-1
begin
    set @I += 1;
    set @J = 0;
    set @K = cast(power(2, @I) as bigint)
    while @J < @K / 2
    begin
        set @J += 1
        insert into dbo.Scratch(id, [name], ParentId, seq, parentSeq)
            values 
                (newid(), cast(@next_node as nvarchar(100)), null, @next_node, @next_node / 2),
                (newid(), cast(@next_node+1 as nvarchar(100)), null, @next_node+1, @next_node / 2);
        set @next_node += 2;
    end
end     

-- update the parent guids
update b
set b.parentId = a.id
from dbo.Scratch a
inner join dbo.Scratch b
on a.seq = b.ParentSeq

-- drop the temporary columns needed for creating the data
--alter table dbo.Scratch drop column parentSeq;
--alter table dbo.Scratch drop column seq;

--select * from dbo.scratch order by seq;
```

Result:

| id | name | parentId | seq | parentSeq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46b16f14-20b9-4388-a7f2-832e2c56215d | 1 |  | 1 |  |
| a613b692-138d-4207-8e84-43cccd0d2476 | 2 | 46b16f14-20b9-4388-a7f2-832e2c56215d | 2 | 1 |
| 0ff8b67a-63fe-4125-b2b9-bb962d67f526 | 3 | 46b16f14-20b9-4388-a7f2-832e2c56215d | 3 | 1 |
| f27f82b6-d1c1-4cb2-810d-4fa21ffef5bc | 4 | a613b692-138d-4207-8e84-43cccd0d2476 | 4 | 2 |
| 346fd62a-6727-4414-975b-2b1659ee40c9 | 5 | a613b692-138d-4207-8e84-43cccd0d2476 | 5 | 2 |
| a8d3928a-6357-47ef-b1d0-0be76fa9233f | 6 | 0ff8b67a-63fe-4125-b2b9-bb962d67f526 | 6 | 3 |
| 1c669bdf-63e1-44af-858b-752003d9a980 | 7 | 0ff8b67a-63fe-4125-b2b9-bb962d67f526 | 7 | 3 |
| 6e7ac3b1-921e-4ddc-a0c7-ad9499992689 | 8 | f27f82b6-d1c1-4cb2-810d-4fa21ffef5bc | 8 | 4 |
| 6786d550-7df8-4ecd-b7ca-6b7658b91b68 | 9 | f27f82b6-d1c1-4cb2-810d-4fa21ffef5bc | 9 | 4 |
| d3113177-cc37-4d55-8b2d-b603345837a8 | 10 | 346fd62a-6727-4414-975b-2b1659ee40c9 | 10 | 5 |
| bb32c1c2-9f75-455e-9aa1-fc38ddd25a6c | 11 | 346fd62a-6727-4414-975b-2b1659ee40c9 | 11 | 5 |
| 1a218245-b6d4-41a7-8117-1b3d0bd2fdd9 | 12 | a8d3928a-6357-47ef-b1d0-0be76fa9233f | 12 | 6 |
| fe8f1882-a89a-4201-83f4-b72e528ba9da | 13 | a8d3928a-6357-47ef-b1d0-0be76fa9233f | 13 | 6 |
| edab3434-c038-406e-bcf0-b6139feff6c0 | 14 | 1c669bdf-63e1-44af-858b-752003d9a980 | 14 | 7 |
| 19007b10-e86f-4fe4-9c0f-8e739f4a5c89 | 15 | 1c669bdf-63e1-44af-858b-752003d9a980 | 15 | 7 |

Comment: Is there a way to do this recursively? For example, your example is up to a depth of 3. If I wanted to add a depth of 100, is my only way to write lines to insert up to 100? The other issue is I am using Guids, so it's harder to just fabricate Guids unless I explicitly mention my Guids

Comment: From what I remember, nodes in a binary tree of depth n is 2^n - 1 - so a tree of depth 100 would have 1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376 nodes.  I know that seems like a lot ... because it is.

Comment: Updated my answer with a version for creating the data in a loop. Nice to have to think about binary trees a little bit for a change.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this (WHILE loop example):

```
DECLARE @TopLevelCount BIGINT = 1
DECLARE @parentFolderId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL

WHILE @TopLevelCount < 2
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TopLevelId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
    INSERT INTO Table(Id, [Name], ParentId)
    VALUES (@TopLevelId, 'Item ' + CAST(@TopLevelCount AS NVARCHAR(5)), @parentFolderId)

    DECLARE @TopLevel2Count BIGINT = @TopLevelCount * 10

    WHILE @TopLevel2Count < (@TopLevelCount * 10) + 2
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TopLevel2Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
        INSERT INTO Table(Id, [Name], ParentId)
        VALUES (@TopLevel2Id, 'Item ' + CAST(@TopLevel2Count AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), @TopLevelId)

        DECLARE @TopLevel3Count BIGINT = @TopLevel2Count * 10

        WHILE @TopLevel3Count < (@TopLevel2Count * 10) + 2
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @TopLevel3Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
            INSERT INTO Table(Id, [Name], ParentId)
            VALUES (@TopLevel3Id, 'Item ' + CAST(@TopLevel3Count AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), @TopLevel2Id)

            DECLARE @TopLevel4Count BIGINT = @TopLevel3Count * 10

            WHILE @TopLevel4Count < (@TopLevel3Count * 10) + 2
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @TopLevel4Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
                INSERT INTO Table(Id, [Name], ParentId)
                VALUES (@TopLevel4Id, 'Item ' + CAST(@TopLevel4Count AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), @TopLevel3Id)

                DECLARE @TopLevel5Count BIGINT = @TopLevel4Count * 10

                WHILE @TopLevel5Count < (@TopLevel4Count * 10) + 2
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @TopLevel5Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
                    INSERT INTO Table(Id, [Name], ParentId)
                    VALUES (@TopLevel5Id, 'Item ' + CAST(@TopLevel5Count AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), @TopLevel4Id)

                    DECLARE @TopLevel6Count BIGINT = @TopLevel5Count * 10

                    WHILE @TopLevel6Count < (@TopLevel5Count * 10) + 2
                    BEGIN
                        DECLARE @TopLevel6Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
                        INSERT INTO Table(Id, [Name], ParentId)
                        VALUES (@TopLevel6Id, 'Item ' + CAST(@TopLevel6Count AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), @TopLevel5Id)

                        SET @TopLevel6Count = @TopLevel6Count + 1
                    END

                    SET @TopLevel5Count = @TopLevel5Count + 1
                END

                SET @TopLevel4Count = @TopLevel4Count + 1
            END

            SET @TopLevel3Count = @TopLevel3Count + 1
        END

        SET @TopLevel2Count = @TopLevel2Count + 1
    END

    SET @TopLevelCount = @TopLevelCount + 1
END
```

This is for a depth of 6. I will mark @topsail's answer is the correct answer for this question as realistically nobody is likely to need such a large depth (I needed 6 in my case).

Comment: Apologies, fixed

Comment: No reason to mark Topsails answer as correct if this is what you used. Mark the most useful answer.